# Comparing two forms of the infinitive

Tags: infinitives

A few issues.

Am I correct in thinking that the first action to happen in 1 and 2 is "when I saw him"? I saw him first then I happened to ... Right?

> 1 I happened to be standing in a line (queue) when I saw him.
>
> 2 I happened to stand in a line (queue) when I saw him.

If my assumption is right. Would these change the order of the actions?

> 3 I had happened to be standing in a line (queue) when I saw him.
>
> 4 I had happened to stand in a line (queue) when I saw him.
>
> 5 I happened to have been standing in a line (queue) when I saw him.
>
> 6 I happened to have stood in a line (queue) when I saw him.

The next issue. If we compare "to be waiting" and "to wait" what will we see?

Does 1 mean

a) A one-off action - When I saw him (that day) I happened to be standing...

b) a repeated action - Every time I saw him, I happened to stand in...

2 means a repeated action - Every time I saw him, I happened to stand in...

Comment: (2), (4) and (6) sound _extremely_ unlikely sentences to me. If you happened to see 'him' just as you were positioning yourself at the back of a queue, you would say something like "I was just joining the queue when I saw him". And, yes, (1) means (a).

Comment: 3 and 5, make sense?

Comment: Well... (3) would make sense with _when I had seen him_ as long as you were telling a story in the past tense and this incident had happened _before_ the events of the story. (5) only makes sense if you mention how long you had been standing for.

Comment: Thank you. To doublecheck - 1 can mean one occasion or a series of occasions?

Comment: It could only mean one occasion - as opposed to something like _I happened always to be standing in a queue when[ever] I saw him_.